# How to prevent vim from classifying blank lines as words

Tags: vim

In vim, I have just noticed that `w` and `b` now catch on blank lines. I have also seen that this is mentioned in the [official vim docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#word) with the statement "An empty line
is also considered to be a word."

I would like to have empty lines not be considered words. That is, given the text

```
foo

bar
```

with the cursor positioned on the last "o" in "foo", I would like to be able to press `w` once and have the cursor go to the "b" in "bar", and not the blank line in between.

I have attempted to modify `iskeyword`, but seeing as the newline (ascii char 10) is not included in any of the default values of `iskeyword`, it is not surprising that this does not produce the desired change.

I suspect that the solution will come from modifying what defines a "word", but apart from modifying `iskeyword`, I have not been able to find information on how to do this. How do I make this change?

Comment: Consider using the `shift+[` and `shift+]` keys to navigate by "paragraph"

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't realize these were vim commands. I'll definitely use these, likely along with the script posted below.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to remap `w`, `b`, `W`, `B` to a custom function, just in the case that you really want to skip the blank lines but get no simple way to approach it.

```
nnoremap <silent> w :call MovePastBlank('w')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> b :call MovePastBlank('b')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> W :call MovePastBlank('W')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> B :call MovePastBlank('B')<cr>

function! MovePastBlank(motion)
  execute 'normal! '.a:motion
  let prev_pos = getpos('.')

  while expand('<cword>') == ''
    execute 'normal! '.a:motion

    let current_pos = getpos('.')
    if current_pos == prev_pos
      return 
    else
      let prev_pos = current_pos
    endif
  endwhile
endfunction
```

Comment: Huge thanks for this! This does exactly what I want on the terminal VI. It does not work on VS Code's Vim extension (found at https://github.com/vscodevim/vim/). On VS Code, the call MovePastBlank('') lines appear in the command area, but don't execute; the result is that w and b don't do anything. Is there a way to make this script work properly with vs code vim?

Comment: Vscodevim is a Vim emulator for vscode. This script is vim-specific vimscript. It's not supported by vscodevim.